# jQuery Mobile Splitview plugin resolution fix on nexus 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

got a problem using the jQuery Mobile Splitview plugin.
The splitview plugin works create on smartphones and tablets, but it doesn't work on the new google nexus 10 maybe because of the high resolution. 
On the nexus 10 it shows only the standard view for smartphones not the tablet view.

Can someone tell me how i can fix this problem? Does someone else have this problem too, maybe with an ipad 4 or a google nexus 10?

Greets

Comment: Please provide a short example, this would make it easier to test...

Comment: http://asyraf9.github.com/jquerymobile-splitview/ thats the demo site and it doesnt work on neuxs 10

Comment: probably you have to adjust the user agent of your browser? you can do that with the Dolphin browser...

Comment: but i dont use the splitview in the browser. Sry my fault. I use it in a hybride app with phonegap.

Comment: I got the answer: change the following code in the jquery.mobile.splitview.js from `var $query = $.mobile.media('screen and (min-width: 480px)') && ($.mobile.media('(-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.2)') || $.mobile.media('(max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.2)'));` to                                                               `var $query = $.mobile.media('screen and (min-width: 480px)') && ($.mobile.media('(-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 2.2)') || $.mobile.media('(max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2.2)'));`